# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 4311

Tags: wordpress

My website https://cijferreeksenoefenen.nl/ is not loading. I have no idea what to do.

It's a problem with this file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8048a10d0ce0b55c4c7b58bcf3aa5f9320191016141723/ae4100

Already tried to fix it but I'm not a developer so no succes...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you provided on WeTransfer ends with:

```
if ( ! apply_filters( 'load_default_widgets', true ) ) {
    return;
}

require_once(
```

The file has been cut off; there should be more code after this. This may be due to a failed upload. You'll need to restore from a backup, or contact the developer or theme author to get a replacement file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had one backup from 2018 so I'm really glad it still worked. Had some errors left after replacing the file but then updated Wordpress and everything seems to function right now :) Merci!